# How to add multiple UIImageViews with same property

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to have multiple images (in this case, basketballs) move around on the screen.

How can I create multiple balls with the same name? I have one ball which is already moving around. So all the other balls should use the same calculation with the same property name for bumping and stuff like that.

Can someone help me? I know Java well, but not Obj C.

**EDIT:**

```
        ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballmovement.x, ball.center.y + ball movement.y);

    if (ball.center.x > self.view.frame.size.width || ball.center.x < 0) {
        ballmovement.x = -1* ballmovement.x;
    }

    if (ball.center.y > self.view.frame.size.height || ball.center.y < 0) {
        ballmovement.y = -1* ballmovement.y;
```

This is my simple calculation. This code is in my loop method. this loop method is called by this code in my viewDidLoad method:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.050 target:self selector:@selector(loop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In the MainView .h file i wrote

```
BasketballView *ball;
```

new Balls are created by this code in my button action method:

```
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfBalls; x++)
    {
        ball = [[BasketballView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random()%100,arc4random()%100, 40, 40) andCustomProperty:@"my string" andAnotherProperty:100];
        [self.view addSubview:ball];
    }
```

When i run my application, only one ball is moving!
do you need more code?
thanks for your help

**EDIT 2:**

every ball is moving now, but they are not moving correctly .. here is what i did. i created a NSMuteableArray. i added this code in my Button action method:

```
            [array addObject:ball];
```

after that, i added in the loop method some code. here is the new loop code that i have right now:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.count;i++){
            ball = [array objectAtIndex:i];

            ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballmovement.x, ball.center.y + ballmovement.y);
            }
if (ball.center.x > self.view.frame.size.width || ball.center.x < 0) {
    ballmovement.x = -1* ballmovement.x;
}

if (ball.center.y > self.view.frame.size.height || ball.center.y < 0) {
    ballmovement.y = -1* ballmovement.y;
```

right now, every ball is changing direction when one ball hits the boarder. so all the other balls move like the this one ball. they ignore the boarders. only if this one ball hits the boarder, they change their direction.
if i put the code for the ball movement inside the for-loop, the balls change their direction everytime one of the balls hits the boarder. they are moving like crazy, because every .5 seconds a ball hits one of the boarders

Comment: yes you can, .. just copy paste [yourView addSubview:yourBall]; multiple times

Comment: @user2710885 since you already are using a custom view, I suggest that you build your movement into the custom view. Then each ball has its own moves associated with it.

Comment: @user2710855 Please look at my answer again. I modified the ball code and added a movement method. Now when you create your ball, you can call [ball startMovement] and the balls should move freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you looking for is a way to add a bunch of objects from the same class. To do this, I would suggest that you overwrite an `UIImageView` class. If you do that, you can add custom properties to the balls. See the example below:

In your header file, you would have the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BasketBallView : UIImageView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *customProperty;
@property (assign) NSInteger anotherProperty;

//custom init method if you want
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andCustomProperty:(NSString *)CustomProperty andAnotherProperty:(NSInteger)AnotherProperty;

-(void)startMovement;

@end
```

The implementation would be something like this:

```
#import "BasketBallView.h"

@implementation BasketBallView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_bb_image.png"]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andCustomProperty:(NSString *)CustomProperty andAnotherProperty:(NSInteger)AnotherProperty
{
    self = [self initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.customProperty = CustomProperty;
        self.anotherProperty = AnotherProperty;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)startMovement{
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.050 target:self selector:@selector(loop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)moveBall{
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + ballmovement.x, self.center.y + ballmovement.y);

    if (self.center.x > self.superview.frame.size.width || self.center.x < 0) {
         ballmovement.x = -1* ballmovement.x;
    }

    if (self.center.y > self.superview.frame.size.height || self.center.y < 0) {
        ballmovement.y = -1* ballmovement.y;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

To then use and access your object from your viewcontroller, do it as follows:

```
BasketBallView *bb = [[BasketBallView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) andCustomProperty:@"my string" andAnotherProperty:100];
[self.view addSubview:bb];
```

You could, of course, throw the above lines of code into a loop, and add it multiple times to the view.

**Edit:**

If you want to add the `BasketBallView` to the view for the Interface Builder, you'll need to customize the `initWithCoder` method in the implementation file. In that method, you would similarly set your image, etc.

I would suggest that you **don't** add the `BasketBallView`s via the Interface Builder, however. Since you need a random number of balls, you need to add them from the code and use the method I outlined above. You would add them like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < yourRandomNumber; i++){
    BasketBallView *bb = [[BasketBallView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) andCustomProperty:@"my string" andAnotherProperty:100];
    [self.view addSubview:bb];
}
```

**You can't add copies of views to another view, in other words, you can't create the ball in the IB, then make copies of it in the code and add it to your view.**

The properties I added to the class are just examples of some customization that you could add to the class if you needed to.

You can certainly still use the `center` property since the `BasketBallView` is an subclass of the `UIImageView`, and therefore inherits all the `UIImageView` properties.

Comment: hello, i tried it your way, still no movement. can you tell me for what are those Properties? My little Program should look like this: I have a Button ("Start").. when you hit it , a random Number of balls (between 1 to 10) appears and they move around. I've tried it with one ball, and it worked (added the ball to the storyboard and linked it with a right click to my property "ball")... Now with your class, i removed the property "ball" and edit the image in the inspector with "coustom class".. does it work like that?

Comment: i did all the ball calculation with the property "ball" .. (for example: ball.center. = ....). Can i keep it like that or do i have to change everything? Thanks for your help!

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer! i deleted everything i did in the storyboard. all the basketballs are on the screen but only one is moving! i have the button action method, where i create a random number and run the for-loop. the for loop creates all the basketballs. but now the basketballs are on the screen (also with random positions). but just 1 is moving. i have all the code for the movements in my "loop"method. in the ViewController.h file i wrote "BasketballView *ball;"and i create the basketballs with ball = [[BaskeballView... , But now still only 1 basketball is moving!do you know why?

Comment: @user2710855 could you post your code where you make the basketballs move?

Comment: i added some new code. The balls are moving now. but not correctly.

Comment: thanks for your help! i have it like this now. it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to iOS7, or can wait another month, Apple's new SpriteKit framework will be able to do a lot of the physics and GPU rendering for you. Then it's just a case of making multiple instances of your "Basketball Class".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you tell me more about using Class methods in other Classes? I know how to create new classes, but i dont know how to really use them in Obj C. For example, how can I create a Image in the "basketball" class, with my image, and display it on my MainView?

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        UIImageView* ball = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"]];
        ball.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20*x, 20, 20);
        [self.view addSubview:ball];
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the uiimageview several times on the screen.... and set tag with number 100 or 1001

like

balview.tag = 100;

```
for (int x=0; x < 5; x++)
{
   [self.view addSubview:ballView];
}
```

do calculation for all in one time

```
forin(UIImageView *view in [self.view subviews])
{
    if (view.tag == 100)
    {
     //do something
    }
}




for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        UIImageView* ball = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"]];
        ball.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20*x, 20, 20);
        [self.view addSubview:ball];
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you explain me how to set the starting point of each subView? because now they are all at the same place.

Comment: the balls are now on the screen, but they don't move like the first ball i created. they are just on one position and dont move. i have a animation loop, and inside this loop, there is all my code for the ball to move.  i dont get the code with the tag and the forin(UIImageView *view in [self.view subviews]) . if i paste this into my loop, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:

1: Add all balls to an array and access them by the index (seems more feasible to me)

2: Add them tags and access them by

```
[self.view viewWithTag:<BallTag>];
```

Edit: Seems like you have chosen the first alternative. Now you need to improve your method for only one ball to move and invoke it whenever you desire.

```
- (void)moveBallWithIndex:(int)idx{

     //for (int i=0; i<array.count;i++){ 
     //Loop removed. It was the reason why all the balls were moving

    BasketballView * ball = [array objectAtIndex:idx];

    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballmovement.x, ball.center.y + ballmovement.y);

    if (ball.center.x > self.view.frame.size.width || ball.center.x < 0) {
        ballmovement.x = -1* ballmovement.x;
    } 

    if (ball.center.y > self.view.frame.size.height || ball.center.y < 0) {
         ballmovement.y = -1* ballmovement.y;

    }
}
```

Edit: It seems like you carried the move method to the ball class, for limitations I can think o fthree alternatives:

1. Create two properties on the ball class named "maxX" and "maxY" during init/set after init and use them in the move method
2. Improve your move method with two parameters like

   ```
   - (void)moveWithhinMaxX:(float)maxX andMaxY:(float)maxY;
   ```

   and use them for limitation inside the move method
3. Improve your move method by giving the superview on the move method like:

   ```
   - (void)moveWithinView:(float)newSuperview{

   //[newSuperview addSubview:self]; add as subview if necessary
   //Use newSuperview's bounds for limitations
   ```

   and inside it you can add the ball as subview to superview and use its bounds for limitation

Comment: Can you teach me how Tags work? Or how Does it work to add My Ball Images to an Array? Thanks.

Comment: ok i tried to add them and it worked , but now i have a new problem... all my balls are in one array , all balls are moving, but they are moving not by themself. they change their direction everytime the first ball hits the boarder. my new code is at the top.

Comment: "//Loop removed. It was the reason why all the balls were moving". But i want that every ball is moving. but they should move with their own bumping calculation. Because right now, every ball is moving, but they dont bump when they hit one of the boarders, they bump and change directions, when one of the balls hit the boarder.

Comment: they should move around independently.

Comment: Theni I think you should create a move method inside the ball, doing that outside will harden things. Then the only thing to do is to invoke the move methods after the balls are created, and randomly invoking them

Comment: It works! but i have one more question! i cant access the size of the view inside the ball class. How can i access it? i tested it with if ball.center > 200 , just to see if it works.

Comment: Improved my answer, I have proposed three alternatives :)